# How to build a subfolder in Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: msbuild, bitbucket-pipelines

I am struggling to configure the build in Bitbucket Pipelines.

It's a C# solution and the code is located in a subfolder, rather than in the root folder of the repository. This is why when I build it, I get the error:

> + dotnet restore
>
> MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.

I've read the docs but there seems to be no option to try to specify a subfolder. How do you configure it then?

Here's my .yml file:

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - dotnetcore
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - export PROJECT_NAME=MyProjectNameHere
          - export TEST_NAME=MyProjectNameHere
          - dotnet restore
          - dotnet build $PROJECT_NAME
          - dotnet test $TEST_NAME
```

Answer (score 6):

Found it by experiment, the docs didn't mention it at all.

You need to use full path and solution filename on two lines and only the folder name on the `restore` line:

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - dotnetcore
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - export PROJECT_NAME=FolderNameHere/MySolution.sln # use the full path and solution file name
          - export TEST_NAME=FolderNameHere/MySolution.sln # use the full path and solution file name
          - dotnet restore FolderNameHere # use only folder name here
          - dotnet build $PROJECT_NAME
          - dotnet test $TEST_NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could `cd` into the subfolder before calling the build commands.

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - dotnetcore
        script:
          - cd MyProject # Set current working directory to subfolder
          - export ...
          - dotnet restore
```

You could also add checks to print the current folder at any time, with a step that runs `pwd` ("print working directory").

Answer (score 0):

Now you can also use the project folders and do not need to use the .sln file in the PROJECT_NAME and TEST_NAME variables.

```
- step:
    caches:
      - dotnetcore
    script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
      - export PROJECT_NAME=YourSolutionFolder/YourProjectFolder
      - export TEST_NAME=YourSolutionFolder/YourTestProjectFolder
      - dotnet restore YourSolutionFolder
      - dotnet build $PROJECT_NAME
      - dotnet test $TEST_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it by experiment.

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - dotnetcore
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - cd MainDir
          - cd SubDir
          - export PROJECT_NAME=MyProject
          - export TEST_NAME=MyProject.Test
          - dotnet restore 
          - dotnet build $PROJECT_NAME
          - dotnet test $TEST_NAME
```